# anaconda: could not use shell script to switch environment

Tags: anaconda, ray

I have anaconda installed. I am using centOS `8.2`, anaconda installation package name is: `Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh` ,

With the initialization, the environment is base. as it shows in the following command line:

```
(base) [sjj@localhost ~]$
```

I wrote a shell script named as env.sh as follows, the purpose it to switch environment:

```
#！/bin/sh

conda activate ray-tutorial
```

It always say:

```
(base) [sjj@localhost ~]$ sh env.sh

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

But if I directly type the command to switch the environment, it works: My question is why shell script does not work in this case?

```
(base) [sjj@localhost ~]$ conda activate ray-tutorial
(ray-tutorial) [sjj@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: I guess you use `sh` which is not in the list of supported shells, I would try the same with `bash`. Also, instead of executing the shell script, try to source it `source env.sh`.

Comment: @user neither you suggestion works!